# How to copy and paste text from one tab to another by javascript (chrome extension)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to copy data (each field has different ElementIds) from site A and paste to site B (similar to a login page). In the past I used `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v` to repeatedly copy paste information between two sites. The structures of site A and site B always keep the same but the context in site A changed according to different people.

I have been thinking about creating a chrome extension to copy the data from site A and paste to site B.

How should I work on it?

**[Additional Explanation]**

Although I am new to JavaScript and Chrome extension, I know how to create a chrome extension and how to read the date of a certain page. The main problem is how can I pass the data I read in the site A (www.a.com/XXX) to site B (www.b.com/XXX), so I can use the data to fill in the site B?

Since I need to repeatedly do this process, I hope I can make a extension so when I click it in site A it retrieves the data. Then I click it in site B it will fill the date into the site B.

It is not for batch process and I need it can be easily used by other people.

Comment: start by using javascript

Comment: @Joe, did my answer help?

Comment: @Maximus Hi Maximus, thank you for the answer. However, this is not the answer I want. I may not express clearly, so I add more explanation.

Comment: @Joe, do you want me to write code for you? I described how you can do that, now I assume you must build the extension yourself.

Comment: @Maximus got it. I tried to read more these days and have a rough idea now. It will be better if you could give me an example :)

Comment: @Joe, I suggest you start putting some code together and then asking several questions focused around specific task and code samples, like `I've tried to read value using this injection script I've written and it didn't work`. I'll take a look then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for copy/pasting and [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)/[event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) for communication. Inject the first script into page A. This script will be responsible for copying data. Inject the second script to page B. This script will be inserting data into the page. Use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to communicate between the scripts through main background/event page.